# vb.net and interface implementation

Tags: vb.net, generics, interface

I want that each class in a certain namespace implement `IEquatable(Of thatClass)` and its corresponding `GetHashCode`.

```
Namespace DAO
    Public Class Product : Implements IEquatable(Of Product)

        Shadows Function Equals(ByVal other As Product) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Product).Equals
        Shadows Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    End Class

End Namespace
```

I can just "remember" to implement the two methods but that would be poor practice.

I could write an interface IDao and again "remember" to let all the classes implement that interface. But an interface can't implement another interface.

```
Public Interface IDao : Implements IEquatable ' <---- NO!
```

Ok, so I could create an abstract class (bad, the Dao classes won't be able to inherit from other classes) and again remember to let all the classes inherit from it:

```
Public MustInherit Class DaoBase : Implements IEquatable(Of DaoBase)

        MustOverride Shadows Function Equals(ByVal other As DaoBase) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of DaoBase).Equals
        MustOverride Shadows Function GetHashCode() As Integer

    End Class

 Public Class Product
        Inherits DaoBase

    Overrides Function Equals(ByVal other As DaoBase) As Boolean
            Return ??? 
    End Function
```

Now the parameter in Equals is a DaoBase, not a Product. I could cast, but...

Or I could generalize the DaoBase like:

```
  Public MustInherit Class DaoBase(Of T) : Implements IEquatable(Of T)

        MustOverride Shadows Function Equals(ByVal other As T) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of T).Equals
        MustOverride Shadows Function GetHashCode() As Integer

    End Class
```

But that means a different DaoBase will be created for each inheriting class.

Is there a way to declare DaoBase non-generic **and** have the subclasses handle the right types?

Nice to have: force each class in a namespace to implement an interface by contract. So I don't have to remember ;)

Answer (score 1):

An interface cannot implement another interface, but it can inherit from another interface.
The following works:

```
Public Interface IDao 
    Inherits IEquatable 

End Interface
```

So you could apply your initial thought with this approach

Comment: It has to inherit from `IEquatable(Of IDao)` and then the type casting problem still applies.

Comment: + 1 Additionally - I question implementing an inherited interface across an entire namespace (or inheriting anything for that matter) simply so that the author "remembers" to do it. Implement an interface if it makes sense for your domain model, and inherit as described for the same reason. but don't inherit simply to make the coding easier - this can lead to pain. Use inheritance/interfaces in a way that makes sense within your domain - not as a means to re-use code or make the writing of code easier. In the end you will accomplish the last two by adhering to good practices on the first two.

Comment: @XIVSolutions: If interface X inherits interface Y, then a variable of type X can be passed to a routine that expects a Y without typecasting.  Interfaces should inherit other interfaces in cases where such implicit type conversion should be allowed, and should not inherit in cases where it should be prohibited.

Comment: You can make it generic, so that `IDao(Of T)` inherits from `IEquatable(Of T)`